# Error on BIRT report analytics: IBM Worklight

Tags: android, birt, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to generate BIRT report on IBM Worklight for an Android device. For this I am following instructions given in the following article:

[Worklight: Generate analytics data and view BIRT reports](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/video-portal/entry/worklight_generate_analytics_data_and_view_birt_reports?lang=en)

The steps I've taken are:

1. Installed BIRT in Eclipse from the Juno repository: Juno - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno
2. Created a Worklight project with and edited worklight.properties (please find code below)
3. Already being installed SQL server with databases: "worklight" and "wl_report"
4. Added the Android environment, Built and Deploy the application and ran the Android application on device. Then I checked the database, it has all tables but there is no data in "**app_activity_report**" table
5. Download "module_44_0_DeviceAnalytics" from the Getting Started page, import it into  Eclipse, click on the Report design and edit it with the database connection.

No Graph is being generated.

**worklight.properties:**

```
wl.db.type=MYSQL
wl.db.url=jdbc:mysql://*.0.0.1:****/worklight
wl.db.username=root
wl.db.password=root

reports.exportRawData=true

wl.reports.db.type=MYSQL
wl.reports.db.url=jdbc:mysql://*.0.0.1:****/wl_report
wl.reports.db.username=root
wl.reports.db.password=root
```

Comment: You've mentioned "Wlreport", but in the quote it shows "wl_report". Make sure that the database name in MySQL is correct (matching the one in worklight.properties).

Comment: yeah i know , but in my code its same, now i have edited in my above code too..:)..the problem is i am not getting data in my "app_activity_report" table after deploy and run on androi dplateform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you made sure to also update initOptions.js (in yourProject\apps\yourApp\common\js folder) and change `connectOnStartup` from "false" to "true"?

Otherwise, the application will not connect to the Worklight Server and no logging to the database (to the app_activity_report table) will take place.

Comment: thanks it works , now i am getting data on "app_activity_report " table , however i have import "module_44_0_DeviceAnalytics" and click on "daily_hits.rptdesign" on report design lay out but giving error like "java.lang.NullPointerException" on a dailog..

Comment: An exception trace would be more helpful. Can't help.